# How to add subdocument to an ElasticSearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

In ElasticSearch, given the following document, Is it possible to add items to the "Lists" sub-document without passing the parent attributes (i.e. Message and tags)?
I have several attributes in the parent document which I dont want to pass every time I want to add one item to the sub-document.

```
{
"tweet" : {
    "message" : "some arrays in this tweet...",
    "tags" : ["elasticsearch", "wow"],
    "lists" : [
        {
            "name" : "prog_list",
            "description" : "programming list"
        },
        {
            "name" : "cool_list",
            "description" : "cool stuff list"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: how do you build the document?

Comment: I am building the entire document as a json document and post it using Powershell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is, how to insert a nested documents.

In your case, you can use the [Update API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) to append a nested document to your list.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/index/tweets/1/_update -d '{
    "script" : "ctx._source.tweet.lists += new_list",
    "params" : {
        "new_list" : {"name": "fun_list", "description": "funny list" }
    }
}'
```

To support nested documents, you have to define your mapping, which is described [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html).

Assuming your type is `tweets`, the follwoing mapping should work:

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/index

curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/index -d'
{
   "settings": {
      "index.number_of_shards": 1,
      "index.number_of_replicas": 0
   },
   "mappings": {
      "tweets": {
         "properties": {
            "tweet": {
               "properties": {
                  "lists": {
                     "type": "nested",
                     "properties": {
                        "name": {
                           "type": "string"
                        },
                        "description": {
                           "type": "string"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

Then add a first entry:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/index/tweets/1 -d '
{
   "tweet": {
      "message": "some arrays in this tweet...",
      "tags": [
         "elasticsearch",
         "wow"
      ],
      "lists": [
         {
            "name": "prog_list",
            "description": "programming list"
         },
         {
            "name": "cool_list",
            "description": "cool stuff list"
         }
      ]
   }
}'
```

And then add your element with:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/index/tweets/1/_update -d '
{
   "script": "ctx._source.tweet.lists += new_list",
   "params": {
      "new_list": {
         "name": "fun_list",
         "description": "funny list"
      }
   }
}'
```